# Auto-tabulizing NOTEPAD++

Tags: tabs, notepad++

I am currently writing a site and because I am the beginner I often use codes from different sides. Depends on this, sometimes I have to tabulize about 200 strings of codes by hand. Do you have a solution for this? If yes, please help me. I didn't find any solution in Internet.

Comment: You can suggest a plugin, but please explain how to install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the IndentByFold plugin: https://www.fesevur.com/indentbyfold/
To install it, at first go to the download page at the site above.
Then select 32bit or 64bit. 
Then go to Downloads and copy the DLL file from the archive.
Then go to Program Files - Notepad++ - Plugins.
There you have to create a folder "IndentByFold" and then copy that DLL file inside it.
Then restart the Notepad++.
Hope I helped you!